# Why is saveOptions member of UI API Record Layout response always empty?

Tags: lightning-web-components, ui-api

I am retrieving Layout information via UI API.  I have tried this both with the lightning UiApi adapter:

```
import { getRecordUi } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';

@wire(getRecordUi, {recordIds: "$recordId", layoutTypes: "Full", modes: "View"}) recordUiResponse;
```

as well as a direct API via workbench:

```
/services/data/v52.0/ui-api/record-ui/a2M1D000000khgWUAQ
```

In both cases, the [Record Layout](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.uiapi.meta/uiapi/ui_api_responses_record_layout.htm#ui_api_responses_record_layout) response record contains the `saveOptions` member, but it is always empty.

I've tried this with several different custom objects, and in each case the result is that same - I get the full reponse, *except* `saveOptions` is always empty.  I've also tried calling the layout endpoint directly (`/services/data/v52.0/ui-api/layout/Object__c`), and passing values for every param instead of relying on default param values.  I am unable to view `saveOptions` in any case.  How can I make this work?

Comment: What saveOption are you expecting? Is this for a custom object? saveOptions are for send email notification, use assignment rule, etc.